# Rotation matrices for arbitrary dimensions

Tags: matrices, transformation, orthonormal

I initially asked this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7330/rotation-matrices-and-prior-invariance-for-arbitrary-dimensions), and someone suggested this may be a better place to get an answer.
I have a question about a rotation matrix, which can be represented in 2 dimensions as:
$$R_{2}(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix} cos\theta & sin\theta \\ -sin\theta & cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
For some arbitrary angle $\theta$. This can be extended to an arbitrary number of dimensions by adding an identity matrix:
$$R_{n}(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix} R_{2}(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & I_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$$

My question is: can any rotation in arbitrary dimensions be represented by a sequence of 2-D rotations? (i.e. a product of row/column permuted matrices of the above type?) It doesn't matter if the sequence is unique or not for my purposes.

If this is true (which I think it would be), does adding a translation affect this representation, or does the rotation need to be carried about the origin for the representation to hold?

$$X'=R_{n}^T(X-x_{0})$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is a consequence of the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) and is proven, for example, in [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/so3-and-su2/). Translations don't affect anything.

Comment: did you make the "stereographic projection" graph in your blog post? What software did you use to do that if so? It looks quite nice!

Comment: @Qiang: no, I took it from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Riemann_sphere1.jpg