# Rotation in high dimension in the direction of given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, rotations

Given two vectors $A$ and $B$ (with high dimension), and an angle $\alpha$. How can one find the vector $C$ which is $A$ rotated over $\alpha$ in the direction of $B$?

If it changes anything: the vectors $A$ and $B$ could be restricted to positive vectors.

Related questions:

[Finding the rotation matrix in n-dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598750/finding-the-rotation-matrix-in-n-dimensions), [Rotation matrices for arbitrary dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22508/rotation-matrices-for-arbitrary-dimensions), [High Dimensional Rotation Matrices As Product of In-Plane Rotations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259427/high-dimensional-rotation-matrices-as-product-of-in-plane-rotations)

Comment: This is really a two dimensional problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat $A$ and the 'x axis' and $B$ (modified to make it orthogonal to $A$) as the 'y axis'.

Let $A' = {A \over \|A\|}$, $\tilde{B} = B-\langle A',B \rangle A'$, $B' = {\tilde{B} \over \|\tilde{B}\|}$.

Then the rotated vector is $\|A\| ((\cos \alpha) A'+ (\sin \alpha) B')$.